# Como realizar esta formula de excel en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2012

Como puedo obtener el resultado de esta formula de excel en una consulta de SQL Server?

**Ejemplo:** =IF(K1432=K1431,0,1)

El resultado es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:** los registros en color rojo son elementos duplicados, con mi formula en excel puedo hacer que el registro unico se marque en 1 (para efectos de contabilizacion) y el resto de elementos duplicados del mismo ID se marque en 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay muchísimas formas de hacer esto, y todo va a depender de la estructura de la tabla y la forma de ordenar las filas de datos. En este caso, voy a asumir que tienes otra columna `Id` con la cual puedes ordenar tus datos (para saber cuál es el valor "único" y cuáles los "duplicados").

```
SELECT  
    Valor,
    CASE
        WHEN N > 1 THEN 0 
        ELSE 1
    END Marca
FROM (
        SELECT 
            Id,
            Valor,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Valor ORDER BY Id) N
        FROM dbo.Tabla
      ) t
ORDER BY t.Valor
;
```

Comment: Excelente, me funciono como esperaba.

Muchas gracias.